# Is there any advantage by using two ports in node?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Can we use two ports for running node in same server ?
So that one port for one type of traffic and another for different traffic.

Is there any advantage by using different ports ? Is it helpful for reducing server load compared to single port with all traffic ?

Comment: Don't use tags that don't apply to your question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use however many ports  you want/need.

No it does not help reduce load at all.  The same code is handling connections at those ports.  Don't think of a port at something physical.  It's just a numeric identification.  Having 5,000 connections on one port is no different than having 5,000 connections on 5,000 ports.  (Although if you had 5,000 ports, the listeners for all of those might have extra overhead if they are poorly implemented.)

Answer (score 1):

As long as running in a single instance, the server load should be the same as Brad mentions.

If you try to distribute traffic loads, you could run separate instances of node, so that even in the same machine, with different ports, you would take advantage of multi-core processing power.

Also consider to use nginx, which nowadays common to use with node.js for load-balancing.